# Issue when trying to achiever infinite scrolling in react js using useref

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, vite, react-infinite-scroll-component

I am trying to achieve infinite scrolling in my react js project, I tried react-infinite-scroll-component package, but it did not work for me. So now I am trying useref here but it is also not working. I am trying to change the state `page` while scrolling hits the bottom of the table, and then that state `page` will be sent to api endpoint which will return more data. But it is not working for me. Here is my code:

```
// ref ----------------------- 
  const tableWrapperRef = useRef(null);

  const handleScroll = () => {
    const wrapper = tableWrapperRef.current;
    if (wrapper) {
      const isScrolledToBottom =
        wrapper.scrollHeight - wrapper.scrollTop === wrapper.clientHeight;
      if (isScrolledToBottom) {
        setPage((prev) => prev + 1);
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const wrapper = tableWrapperRef.current;
    if (wrapper) {
      wrapper.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
    }
    return () => {
      if (wrapper) {
        wrapper.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
      }
    };
  }, []);

// api calling

  useEffect(() => {
    if (debouncedSearchQuery.trim() === "") {
      // If the search query is empty, fetch all items
      axios
        .get(
          `${
            import.meta.env.VITE_APP_API_BASE_URL
          }/api/transaction/account-transactions/${
            userInformation._id
          }/${page}/15`,
          {
            headers: apiHeaders,
          }
        )
        .then((res) => {
          const decrypted = decryptData(res.data.data);
          setUserTransactions(decrypted.transactionList);
          console.log("all", decrypted.transactionList);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          const decrypted = decryptData(err.response.data.data);
          if (decrypted.status === false) {
          }
        });
    } else {
      // If there is a search query, make the API call with the search query
      axios
        .get(
          `${
            import.meta.env.VITE_APP_API_BASE_URL
          }/api/transaction/search-account-transactions/${
            userInformation?._id
          }/${page}/20/${debouncedSearchQuery}`,
          {
            headers: apiHeaders,
          }
        )
        .then((res) => {
          const decrypted = decryptData(res.data.data);
          setUserTransactions(decrypted.transactionList);
          console.log("search_results", decrypted.transactionList);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          const decrypted = decryptData(err.response.data.data);
          if (decrypted?.status === false) {
            setUserTransactions([]);
          }
          console.log(decrypted, "decrypted");
        });
    }
  }, [page, debouncedSearchQuery, userInformation]);
```

```
<Card noborder>
        <div className="md:flex justify-between items-center mb-6">
          <div className=" flex gap-2 items-center">
            <h4 className="card-title">{t("All transactions")}</h4>
            <div
              className=" flex items-center rounded-[10px] bg-[#FFF] pt-[0.7rem] pb-[0.7rem] pl-2"
              style={{
                boxShadow: "0px 4.32752px 35.70205px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) ",
                //   padding: "0 1rem",
              }}
            >
              <span className=" text-3xl text-slate-900  cursor-pointer hover:text-slate-600">
                <Icon icon="ic:twotone-search" />
              </span>
              <input
                placeholder={"Search" + "..."}
                value={searchQuery}
                onChange={handleSearchChange}
                className=" "
                style={{ border: "none", outline: "none" }}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="date-range-custom2 relative">
            <Datepicker
              inputClassName="input-class"
              containerClassName="container-class"
              value={date}
              onChange={handleValueChange}
              showShortcuts={true}
              primaryColor={"blue"}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          className="overflow-x-auto -mx-6"
          ref={tableWrapperRef} //calling ref here
        >
          <div className="max-h-[400px] overflow-y-auto custom-scrollbar">
            <div className="inline-block min-w-full align-middle">
              <table className="min-w-full divide-y divide-slate-100 table-fixed dark:divide-slate-700">
                <thead className="bg-slate-200 dark:bg-slate-700 sticky top-0">
                  <tr className="">
                    <th className="table-th " scope="col">
                      {" "}
                      #
                    </th>
                    <th className="table-th " scope="col">
                      {" "}
                      Date & Time
                    </th>
                    <th className="table-th  text-left" scope="col">
                      {" "}
                      Transaction ID
                    </th>
                    <th className="table-th  text-left" scope="col">
                      {" "}
                      Payment Type
                    </th>
                    <th className="table-th  text-left" scope="col">
                      {" "}
                      Name
                    </th>
                    <th className="table-th  text-left" scope="col">
                      {" "}
                      Type
                    </th>
                    <th className="table-th  text-left" scope="col">
                      {" "}
                      Amount
                    </th>
                    <th className="table-th  text-left" scope="col">
                      {" "}
                      Status
                    </th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody className="bg-white divide-y divide-slate-100 dark:bg-slate-800 dark:divide-slate-700">
                  {userTransactions?.length > 0 && (
                    <>
                      {userTransactions?.map((transaction, index) => (
                        <tr
                          key={transaction._id}
                          className="text-slate-800 font-semibold"
                        >
                          <td className="table-td text-slate-500 font-normal">
                            {index + 1}
                          </td>
                          <td className="table-td text-slate-500 font-normal">
                            {new Date(transaction.createdAt).toLocaleString()}
                          </td>
                          <td className="table-td text-slate-500 font-normal">
                            {transaction.reference_id}
                          </td>
                          <td className="table-td text-slate-500 font-normal">
                            {transaction.service_type === "wallet_to_wallet"
                              ? "Wallet to Wallet"
                              : transaction.service_type === "deposite_by_admin"
                              ? "Deposited by Admin"
                              : transaction.service_type === "withdraw_by_admin"
                              ? "Withdrawed by Admin"
                              : transaction.service_type}
                          </td>

                          <td className="table-td text-slate-500 font-normal">
                            {transaction.account.user.first_name}{" "}
                            {transaction.account.user.last_name}
                          </td>
                          <td className="table-td text-slate-500 font-normal">
                            {transaction.type}
                          </td>
                          <td className="table-td text-slate-500 font-normal">
                            {transaction?.currency?.symbol}
                            {transaction.amount.toFixed(2)}
                          </td>
                          <td className="table-td text-slate-500 font-normal">
                            <span
                              className={`${
                                transaction.status === "completed"
                                  ? "text-success-500 bg-success-500"
                                  : "text-danger-500 bg-danger-500"
                              } inline-block px-3 min-w-[90px] text-center mx-auto py-1 rounded-[999px] bg-opacity-25 `}
                            >
                              {transaction.status}
                            </span>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      ))}
                    </>
                  )}
                </tbody>
              </table>
              {loading && (
                <div className="w-full flex justify-center items-center min-h-[10vh]">
                  <h6>Loading...</h6>
                </div>
              )}
              {userTransactions?.length === 0 && (
                <div className=" w-full flex justify-center items-center min-h-[10vh]">
                  <h6>No transactions found</h6>
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Card>
```